# Meteor Up Deploy is not working anymore post Meteor 1.2 update

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

using command line too mup deploy, my meteor application no longer deploys to digital ocean. the error is here:

```
x Invoking deployment process: FAILED

-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
Latest deployment failed! Reverted back to the previous version.
-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
.1.0 node_modules/ansi-styles

chalk@0.5.1 node_modules/chalk

escape-string-regexp@1.0.3 node_modules/escape-string-regexp

supports-color@0.2.0 node_modules/supports-color

has-ansi@0.1.0 node_modules/has-ansi

strip-ansi@0.3.0 node_modules/strip-ansi

eachline@2.3.3 node_modules/eachline

type-of@2.0.1 node_modules/type-of

amdefine@1.0.0 node_modules/amdefine

asap@2.0.3 node_modules/asap

underscore@1.5.2 node_modules/underscore

meteor-promise@0.5.0 node_modules/meteor-promise

promise@7.0.4 node_modules/promise

source-map-support@0.3.2 node_modules/source-map-support

semver@4.1.0 node_modules/semver

source-map@0.1.32 node_modules/source-map

fibers@1.0.5 node_modules/fibers
```

If anyone could help, that would be amazing. +100 for you.

Comment: I got the same error once when my mup.json was messed up. Could you post that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded a project to Meteor 1.2 and suddenly I was receiving same error as you when I tried to deploy. After failing to find a solution, I seen a comment on a similar issue that suggest trying mupx. I installed mupx and followed the migration guide https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/tree/mupx#migrating-from-meteor-up-0x and I can deploy again.